# javascript to save history

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html form which are paginated.I need javascipt that can save the history of value of input, user click next pages and when return to previous page can see what was wrote.

Answer (score 5):

You have several options. You can for example use [local storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_webstorage.asp).

But since that is not supported in older browsers, you can fall back to a cookie mechanism for example. Check out [jstorage.info](http://www.jstorage.info) for a library that handles this fallback behaviour for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use Cookies method in javascript to store text box value. 
[Keep a JavaScript variables value after a page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841771/keep-a-javascript-variables-value-after-a-page-refresh) this page gives more information about cookies.