# Keep a JavaScript variables value after a page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am working with one project in which variable is assigned a value i need that value when browser is refreshed.Is there any way get that value?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Cookies**

The best solution is to use *cookies*. A cookie, also known as an HTTP cookie, web cookie, or browser cookie, is usually a small piece of data sent from a website and stored in a user's web browser while a user is browsing a website (from Wikipedia).

Using a cookie you can save the *state* and later read it and use it.

With jQuery it is very easy to use cookies.

To set:

```
$.cookie("var", "10");
```

To get:

```
$.cookie("var")
```

To delete:

```
$.cookie("var", null);
```

**Local Storage**

When you want to save localy great amount of data, you have another opportunity — to use local storage (since HTML5). You can do it directly using JavaScript or using one of available jQuery plugins.

for example, with `totalStorage`:

```
var scores = new Array();
scores.push({'name':'A', points:10});
scores.push({'name':'B', points:20});
scores.push({'name':'C', points:0});
$.totalStorage('scores', scores);
```

Comment: Using cookies is _not_ the best solution, because cookies are also shared with the web server.

Comment: @Alnitak It usually will be if you are required to support browsers which don't have local storage.

Comment: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Answer (score 4):

You can place that value in a cookie.

The complete list of alternatives is

- Standard HTTP cookies
- Local Shared Objects (Flash cookies)
- Silverlight Isolated Storage
- Storing cookies in RGB values of auto-generated, force-cached PNGs using HTML5 Canvas  ag to read pixels (cookies) back out
- Storing cookies in Web history
- Storing cookies in HTTP ETags
- Storing cookies in Web cache
- window.name caching
- Internet Explorer userData storage
- HTML5 Session Storage
- HTML5 Local Storage
- HTML5 Global Storage
- HTML5 Database Storage via SQLite

[Evercookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evercookie)

Answer (score 3):

You can store it in a cookie. Or use local storage if supported by the browser.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$.cookie("key", value)` to set the value, and `$.cookie("key")` to get the saved value.

**EDIT:** A small tutorial on how you use cookies in jQuery: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/