# Light solution for storing persistent, local data for a Javascript application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, persistent-storage

I'm building an HTML5 / Javascript / jQuery application for personal use. The application needs to literally just store two numbers in order to be able to function. What is the absolute lightest way I can store two numbers between script executions and page reloads? Ideally, the solution would not require the application to run on a server.

Comment: cookies, local storage or serverside !

Comment: My understanding is that Javascript can't modify local files, so wouldn't that rule out both cookies and straight filesystem local storage?

Comment: Javascript can modify cookies as long as the cookie isn't set to http only. Also, localstorage isn't file system storage. It's within the browser.

Comment: What does not modifying local files have to do with cookies and localstorage?

Comment: `localStorage` in the browser, not like, an actual file.

Comment: and localstorage is not inside any filesystem file it on the browser

Comment: Sorry, guys, I'm still new to this stuff. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: If you need not to be restricted to strings, you might want to check out JQuery's `data()` function. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Comment: @MirroredFate `.data` does not survive a page reload

Comment: @Alnitak That is true. I wasn't thinking that he stated "between script executions" he was referring to page reloads... but I suppose that would make sense.

Comment: @MirroredFate Sorry 'bout that. I'll edit my question to make that more clear.

Comment: @NathanArthur No worries, no worries. In that case, have a link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11842059/771665 - or two: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2010948/771665

Comment: @NathanArthur one point to remember with cookies is that they are also shared with the web server, which may disclose information that you don't want the server to have.  HTML5 localStorage doesn't do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`localStorage` would be easiest:

```
localStorage.setItem('a', 1);   // or localStorage.a = 1
localStorage.setItem('b', 2);
```

and to retrieve:

```
var a = +localStorage.getItem('a');  // or just a = +localStorage.a
```

Note that `localStorage` can *only* store strings, hence the `+` operator in that last line to cast the stored value back into a number.  If you want to store objects, use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`.

Whether to use the direct properties or `setItem` style access is mostly a matter of personal choice.  That said, in *theory* the methods are more rigorous and recommended as they avoid any possibility of confusing the built-in properties of the `localStorage` object with the keys that you're trying to store.  Also, the methods can be shimmed on older browsers but direct property access cannot.

Comment: Beware localstorage not supported by IE7. Have a look here http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage

Comment: Beware, shim available on [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal the OP said HTML5, thus ruling out IE7/8

Comment: Yes, tis true. And it'll be only for my personal use, so I can afford to worry less about compatability. But thank you for the warnings, nonetheless; and thank you, @Alnitak, for the concise and extremely helpful answer! I'll be trying this solution first. +1!

Comment: Thanks again, Alnitak, for the great answer! It's the one I used, and works like a charm. Accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Local storage is a good idea depending on your browser, here's a very good write up: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Answer (score 1):

Plan old cookies will work as well.
To set a cookie:

```
document.cookie = "MyNumber=1; expires=Fri, 3 Aug 2001 20:47:11 UTC; path=/";
```

To traverse the cookies:

```
var cookies = document.cookie.split(";"), i;
for(i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++)
{
  console.log(cookies[i]);
}
```

Comment: +1 for giving a concise and useful example of cookie use! I just may go this route should I decide later that I want higher compatibility.

Comment: @NathanArthur If you want higher compatibility, use the shims that adeneo linked to in my answer, that use cookies as an alternate storage but still preserve the `localStorage` API.

Comment: Great idea, @Alnitak. I just might do that.