# What happens exactly in AngularJS when page refreshes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I was wondering what exactly happens to data, scopes, caches (and other Angular concepts I might not know of yet) in Angular, when you manually refresh the page.

**Context**

I have a tree-like hierarchical data, that is generated from flat array in a service and rendered in a view by using recursive `ng-template` and `ng-repeat`. Each route in my app has different tree based on parameter (but generated from the same array).

**Problem**

When I display tree first time, it renders fine. Then, I select other route and generate tree for it, also fine. If I then go back and select first route, few unnecessary elements are rendered in the view (I checked if tree i generated was flawed but it's correct). If I repeat this action few times i get error:

`Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`

When I see corrupted view (with unnecessary elements) and refresh the page, **it renders fine**. 
After I checked that passed data is correct, I thought that propably some internal Angular buffer or cache gets filled up during the recursive rendering and it doesn't get emptied when I switch between views.

**Question/s**

- What exactly is emptied in Angular when you refresh the page?
- How can you empty only relevant cache in my case?

Comment: Hello! Please accept my answer if it solves your problem. :) [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/170863)

Answer (score 2):

> What exactly is emptied in Angular when you refresh the page?

AngularJS is a JavaScript framework.

Like in native JS, everything is emptied when you refresh your page.

If you want to save values between refreshes, you have to use a browser storage system.

There are several posts about this topic:

- [How to get JS variable to retain value after page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206322/how-to-get-js-variable-to-retain-value-after-page-refresh)
- [Keep a JavaScript variables value after a page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841771/keep-a-javascript-variables-value-after-a-page-refresh)
- [retain angular variables after page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26118851/retain-angular-variables-after-page-refresh)